# Sending Push Notifications to Specific SquareUp Devices

Tags: apple-push-notifications, square

I'm working on an app that uses the Square API to react to Point-of-sale events.  For example, a customer goes to a take-out restaurant.  The restaurant uses Square to accept payments.  The customer pays cash.  At that point, Square sends a notification to a custom webhook with the PAYMENT_UPDATED flag.  Then, the app I'm working on *should* send a push (APNS) notification to the device that just accepted the cash payment.

The problem is that I haven't found a way to single out a particular device within a Square location.  So what ends up happening is that all devices registered to a Square account get the push notification.

The user registration workflow is as follows:

- A business launches the app and gives permission to receive push notifications (this is where we get and save the device token).
- The business registers for an account.
- The business authenticates with Square (allows our app to receive Square notifications).

I feel like there should be a way to associate a device token used for APNS with a device ID linked to a Square Location (and subsequently accessed via Square's Location API), but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any thoughts or suggestions?  Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The code isn't really the issue.  By that I mean whether we're using PHP, Java, Ruby, etc, the issue remains the same.  The only solution I can think of would be to use Square's SDKs to build a completely custom POS system, but that'd be like using a sludge hammer to put a tac in a wall.

The ultimate goal is to simply create a relationship between a Square device and a user's device I have stored as a record in my sql database. *Seems* like it should be straight forward, but not so much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Is it possible for you to edit your original question to show what code you have so far? For us to understand what you are concretely trying.

Comment: Couldn't you identify the device while they are installing and setting up your custom app?

Comment: That was my initial thought.  The problem is that there is no way to associate the device as we've identified it with square.  Square allows stores to use their POS solution at multiple locations.  At each location, a store may have multiple 'registers,' i.e., devices.  The furthest down the chain we can go is the location (not to the individual devices below that).